# rails 5 devise - undefined method 'api' for Api::V1::SessionsController:Class

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

Working with rails 5 trying to create a simple api to register users.

**Controller:**

```
class Api::V1::SessionsController < Devise::SessionsController
  protect_from_forgery
  respond_to :json
  skip_before_action :verify_authenticity_token #, only: [:create]

    api :POST, "/v1/create_account", "Create User Account"
    param :user, Hash do
    param :email, :undef
    param :password, :undef
  end

  def create_account
    user = params[:user]

    existing_user = User.find_by_email user[:email].strip

    return email_already_taken if !existing_user.nil?

    user = User.create(:email => user[:email],
                        :password => user[:password],
                        :password_confirmation => user[:password])
  end

end
```

**Routes:**

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  devise_for :admin_users

  namespace :api, defaults: {format: "json"} do

  namespace :v1 do

  devise_for :users, :controllers => {:sessions => "api/v1/sessions"}, :path_prefix => 'api/v1'

      devise_scope :user do
        post :create_account, to: "sessions#create_account"
      end
  end
end
end
```

**Trace:**

The trace is talking about the api: POST piece of the controller but why is it giving this error??

```
ActionController::RoutingError (undefined method `api' for Api::V1::SessionsController:Class):

app/controllers/api/v1/sessions_controller.rb:6:in `<class:SessionsController>'
app/controllers/api/v1/sessions_controller.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
  Rendering /Users/local/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/actionpack-5.0.0.1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/routing_error.html.erb within rescues/layout
  Rendering /Users/local/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/actionpack-5.0.0.1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_trace.html.erb
  Rendered /Users/local/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/actionpack-5.0.0.1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_trace.html.erb (1.8ms)
  Rendered collection of /Users/local/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/actionpack-5.0.0.1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/routes/_route.html.erb [31 times] (10.4ms)
  Rendered /Users/local/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/actionpack-5.0.0.1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/routes/_table.html.erb (6.7ms)
  Rendering /Users/local/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/actionpack-5.0.0.1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_request_and_response.html.erb
  Rendered /Users/local/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/actionpack-5.0.0.1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_request_and_response.html.erb (9.7ms)
  Rendered /Users/local/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/actionpack-5.0.0.1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/routing_error.html.erb within rescues/layout (112.5ms)
source=rack-timeout id=43f3c961f7e1e94e4ffe0a55b167d831 timeout=15000ms service=415ms state=completed
```

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: which extra library `gem` are you using? because ` api :POST` is not defined in `Rails`

Comment: API relevant gems are `gem 'rest-client'
gem 'nokogiri'` Thanks for your help @illusionist

Comment: are you using `https://github.com/Apipie/apipie-rails` gem? the syntax is similar to this gem

Comment: @illusionist wow, I had missed that gem and that's exactly what it was missing; however, now I'm getting this: `Could not find devise mapping for path "/api/v1/create_account". This may happen for two reasons: 1) You forgot to wrap your route inside the scope block. For example: devise_scope :user do get "/some/route" => "some_devise_controller" end 2) You are testing a Devise controller bypassing the router. If so, you can explicitly tell Devise which mapping to use: @request.env["devise.mapping"] = Devise.mappings[:user]` Thanks again man have spent a while looking into this

Comment: @illusionist I was able to fix the above method by moving my `devise_for :users, :controllers => {:sessions => "api/v1/sessions"}, :path_prefix => 'api/v1'` line outside of all namespaces in the routes